# Left floated div after the right floated div when small width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tkKth/

When I'm resizing my window (set `.container {width:200px;}`), the left div appears after the right div. Is there a way to do this with css, when the divs left/right change their position in the html doc? 
-> 
`<div class="left">Left div</div> <div class="right">Right div</div>`

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Apparently you have an example that does what you want. What's the problem that needs solving?

Comment: @user1129682: He wants it to behave exactly the way it already does, but he'd like `.left` to come before `.right` in the HTML. The usual justification for this is "SEO purposes".

Comment: I see. I didn't notice the div ordering in HTML. Well, the problem seems to be the intuitive(TM) order in which browsers render stuff. I'm not posting this as an answer, b/c I don't have the time to try it out, but what may work is putting another div around the two problematic divs and set direction to "rtl".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some years later, flexbox is well supported, so this can be achieved with:

```
.container { 
    display: flex; 
}

.left {
    order: 2;
}

.right {
    order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

6on your example http://jsfiddle.net/tkKth/ the right div is before the left

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right">Right div</div>
<div class="left">Left div
</div>​
```

on your question it's the other way around

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">Left div</div>
<div class="right">Right div</div>
</div>​
```

if the .container width is <= .left width & .right width, first in first served

if the left height is fixed (for the example 36px), you can use media queries with min-device-width: if the screen is below 600px, and add this for .right

```
top:36px; /* equivalent to .left height*/
position:absolute;
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly - I want it to behave exactly as in the jsfiddle when the .left is before the .right in the markup. SEO purposes, as @thirtydot said.

Comment: is .left having a fixed height?

Comment: unfortunatly not - I'm searching the most flexible answer ;) but yes, this could be a possibility, thanks for that.

Comment: it's possible to get the div height with jquery http://api.jquery.com/height/ and trigger a change on http://api.jquery.com/resize/, but in pure css I'm not sure it's possible.